# jmeter save response to a file ,the file size up to 10MB, when test file is 50MB

Tags: jmeter

i just test a http request ,it will be download a 50MB file , but the "Save the Responses to a File" save a file up to 10 MB, how to set set that i can download the full size of the file in command line

Answer (score 1):

Add this line `document.max_size=0` to your `user.properties` file or uncomment it in the `jmeter.properties` file. It is suggested to add to the user.properties file.

The default size for document parsing is 10Mb. If you set this value to zero (0) then there will be no checking for 10 MB. To invoke the properties file, you have to restart your JMeter.

Comment: sorry ,there will throw a exception "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect"

Comment: You can pass this argument via command line putting `-J` before the property like this `-Jdocument.max_size=0` while running your test from the Non-GUI mode. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is `httpsampler.max_bytes_to_store_per_request` JMeter property which defaults to 10 megabytes so you can increase it according to your response size if you need to get the file stored. It can be amended in 2 ways:

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   httpsampler.max_bytes_to_store_per_request=62914560
   ```

   this will increase the maximum response size for [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers to 60 megabytes, JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up
2. Pass the property via [-J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jhttpsampler.max_bytes_to_store_per_request=62914560 -m -t test.jmx -l test.jtl
   ```

   in this case restart will not be required, but the property will be changed only for the current JMeter session

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: thanks,  when i add the line into user.properties,it will throw a exception "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect" , it is success to do in second way

Comment: Hi Tim.song, Please check for the above property in `jmeter.properties` file under bin folder.